# max value and min value time complexity O in c++

Tags: c++

Does any one know for following two method to find max and min value for same length vector which one is faster in C++ :

1.

```
std::sort(vector.begin(),vector.end());
vector.erase(std::unique(vector.begin(),vector.end()),vector.end());
min=vector.front();
max=vector.back();
```

2.

```
max=*max_element(vector.begin(),vector.end());
min=*min_element(vector.begin(),vector.end());
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: For complexity, read the docs. For *"what is faster"*, measure. Also, use `std::minmax_element`.

Comment: All of the algorithms have a documented complexity.    No need to use `erase()` after sorting a vector in order to find min and max.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sort (quicksort) has an average `O(n*log2(n))` complexity.

Finding min or max of an array has just `O(n)` complexity.

Therefore the second is much faster.

Comment: *"Therefore the second is much faster."* That's not true like this. All the complexity comparison tells us that there is some `N` such that the second one is faster for all `n>N`. For `n < N`, either may be faster.

Comment: Quicksort is not guaranteed to be O(nlogn) but instead degenerates to O(n^2) given a bad pivot. For a stable sort, use heap sort or other kinds.

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon : That's why I wrote "in average". Heap sort has guaranteed complexity, on the other hand, the single operation is more complicated, therefore quicksort is commonly preferred and in average it wins. And yes, you're right, Baum Mit Augen, for small numbers the numbers may be different, even sort() functions usually prefer few simple comparisons for low number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

This `sort()` function is, basically, a hybrid implementation of quick sort, heap sort, and insertion sort. By default, it uses quick sort, but if quick sort is doing unfair partitioning and taking more than `(N*log(N))` time, it switches to heap sort; when the size of the array becomes tiny, it switches to insertion sort.

In the first example first, you are sorting your vector using `sort` function whose time complexity is `O(N*log(N))`, then you are erasing unique elements in the vector which will take more then you are finding max and min elements in a vector which will eventually take more than `O(N*log(N))` time .

In the second example you are just finding max and min element using *max_element and *min_element whose overall time complexity will be O(N) which is obviously better than `O(N*log N)`.

Or you could've simply run a for loop to find a max and min element whose time complexity would be `O(N)`.